# Transferring CSV file to a Python list

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to get data from a CSV file to a list in Python. This is what I have so far:

```
import csv

with open('RawEirgrid2.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    M = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

print(M[0])
```

I'm trying to print the first item in the list just confirm the code is working (it's currently not). I get the following error:

> TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

In every example I look at it appears it should be subscriptable, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: Aside: are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  Your `print` syntax makes it seem like Python 3, but your `open` makes it seem like Python 2.  (If it's Python 3, you need to use `open(filename, 'r', newline='')` instead of `open(filename, 'rb')`.

Comment: Thanks. It was 3. That solved my next problem. It's working as I want now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these will work:

```
with open('RawEirgrid2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print next(reader)
```

```
with open('RawEirgrid2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    lines = list(reader)

print lines[0]
```

```
with open('RawEirgrid2.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        print line
        break  # stop after the first line
```

The object returned by `csv.reader` is iterable, but not a sequence, so cannot be subscripted. Note that if you try to use `reader` outside of the with statement, the file will have been closed, and it will error - the file is not actually read until you ask for the lines.

Comment: "_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes" is not a solution

Comment: @fsalazar_sch: Both the question and this answer contain code for Python 2.7, which is incompatible with whatever 3.x Python you're using.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
import csv

with open('RawEirgrid2.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    M = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))

print(M[0])
```

Comment: .. why not simply `M = list(csv etc)`, if we're exhausting it all at once anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), e.g:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("yourfile.dat",delimiter=",")
```

This will make `data` a numpy array with as many rows and columns as are in your file

Answer (score 1):

M is actually a iterable, not a list. You can use following

```
next(M)
```

or

```
l=[k for k in M]
print l[0]
```

Edited for @Eric's tip on deprecation.

Comment: Note that `iterator.next()` is deprecated in favor of `next(iterator)`